# Show different error messages in React (form validation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If the phone number is invalid I want to show "invalid phone number" error message, but if the email is invalid I want to show "invalid email address". If both wrong, then show both error messages. And I need to `return null` because I want the function to break if there is an error. The problem is that now it shows both error messages for each case.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            loading: false,
            showError: false
        };
    }

if (!this.state.phone.match(numbers) || !this.state.email.match(regEx)) {
            this.setState({ showError: true }, () => {
                setTimeout(() => this.setState({ showError: false }), 2000);
            });
            return null;
}

<label htmlFor="phone">
                        PHONE{' '}
                        {this.state.showError && (
                           <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>Invalid phone number.</span>
                        )}
</label>

<label htmlFor="email">
                        EMAIL{' '}
                        {this.state.showError && (
                            <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>Invalid email address.</span>
                        )}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (!this.state.phone.match(numbers)) {
            this.setState({ showPhoneError: true }, () => {
                setTimeout(() => this.setState({ showPhoneError: false }), 2000);
            });
        }

        if (!this.state.email.match(regEx)) {
            this.setState({ showEmailError: true }, () => {
                setTimeout(() => this.setState({ showEmailError: false }), 2000);
            });
        }

        if (!this.state.email.match(regEx) || !this.state.phone.match(numbers)) {
            return null;
        }
```

I fixed it like this, although this is not the best practice I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var validation = `${
        ! name
        ? //error message here
        :! phone
        ? //error message here
        : phone.length < 2 // length
        ? //error message here
        : !email
        ? //error message here
        : email && !CheckEmail(email)
        ? //error message here
        : true
    }`;

 if (validation === 'true') {
      // api call or else
   } else {
     this.setState({showError:validation});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way to handle error for each element. i haven't tried this code but it might help you.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        loading: false,
        showErrors:{},
     };
}

//This way you can handle error for phone uniquely
!this.state.phone.match(numbers)?
    this.setState({showErrors:{...this.state.showErrors, phone:true}})
    :
    this.setState({showErrors:{...this.state.showErrors, phone:false}})

//This is for email
!this.state.email.match(regEx)?
    this.setState({showErrors:{...this.state.showErrors, email:true}})
    :
    this.setState({showErrors:{...this.state.showErrors, email:false}})


<label htmlFor="phone">
    PHONE{' '}
    {this.state.showErrors.phone && (
        <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>Invalid phone number.</span>
    )}
</label>

<label htmlFor="email">
    EMAIL{' '}
    {this.state.showErrors.email && (
        <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>Invalid email address.</span>
    )}
</label>
```